# MVVM Xamarin app

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am building an app with Xamarin, using a PCL project, so I have my core functionality there, with platform specific implementations in different projects. I am using the MVVM structure, but with Xamarin I have complicated things. I am using Xamarin.Auth, which allows OAuth2 logins, but it is only available on the .ios and .droid projects.

So I have a "Log in with?" prompt on a view in the core project. Then I go to the platform specific project which calls a Custom Renderer (model shown [here](https://github.com/rlingineni/Xamarin.Forms_Authentication)).

Here is the code in the renderer, which needs to be "customised" based on the authenticator selected by the user.

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
                               clientId: "xxx", // your OAuth2 client id (For FB Also called App-ID)
                               scope: "", // the scopes for the particular API you're accessing, delimited by "+" symbols
                               authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"), // the auth URL for the service (i.e FB, Twitter)
                               redirectUrl: new Uri ("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")); // the redirect URL for the service
```

What is the correct way of doing this? Do I use public variables to communicate this, pass the details through? etc. What is the simplest solution?

Comment: What do you mean by, _"the correct way of doing this"_ and _"to communicate this"_? What is _"this"_ in your case? Do you need to pass a token back for further use? It is not entirely clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Demitrian I mean what is a typical way of dealing with my problem in MVVM. I am trying to use different OAuth values for whichever provider is selected by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a dependency class,that's the correct way.

Don't use a renderer, do all the visual work if possible in the core and let the specific of OAuth to the class.

To do this you create an interface exposing the methods you need to use and then in the specific projects you create a class implementing the interface and decorated with the Dependency attribute.

When you need to use it you ask to the DependencyService for an instance of your interface and it will retrieve the correct class from the specific projects.

Here is the documentation about DependencyService: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would create an interface in PCL and then create classes in the platform-specific projects that implement it.

In your case, it might be something like this

```
public interface IAuthenticateService
{
       Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(string clientId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
}
```

AuthenticateResult should be a class that is also available in PCL.
Once you got that, you would just inject interface into your view models.
Note, that you have to register your interface implementation in a platform-specific project.

MVVMCross is a relatively good framework that might help you with what you are trying to achieve.